# Connection to wifi in debian 9

Tags: linux, drivers, wifi-configuration, debian-stretch

I have two OS on my PC (Windows 10 and Debian 9). When using Debian I can connect to router only if the PC is near the router. When the PC is in another room, debian doesn't detect the network and the router disconnects. When using Windows 10 in the other room, the network works OK.

How can solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your answer and use commas, dots, etc. Make sentences so we can read what you mean.

Comment: the router signal is very weak when I use debian but is good when I use win10

Comment: why I Force to move my laptop near the router to get  strength signal and When I moved away signal is very very weak

Comment: but when using win10  I have  strength signal in any room